# UWP - Refreshing listview and CollectionViewSource

Tags: c, xaml, listview, uwp, collectionviewsource

I have created `ChatMessageGroup` and `ChatMessageGroupCollection`  and  a `ListView` with `ItemsSource` set to `CollectionViewSource`:

```
<ListView x:Name="ChatMessageLv" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedChat.ChatMessageGroupCollection.Cvs.View}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ChatMessageDataTemplateSelector}">
```

```
public class ChatMessageGroup : IGrouping<DateTime, ChatMessage>, INotifyCollectionChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<ChatMessage> _chatMessages;
        public DateTime Key { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<ChatMessage> ChatMessages
        {
            get { return _chatMessages; }
            set
            {
                if (_chatMessages != null)
                    _chatMessages.CollectionChanged -= CollectionChanged;

                _chatMessages = value;
                _chatMessages.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
            }
        }


        public ChatMessageGroup()
        {
            ChatMessages = new ObservableCollection<ChatMessage>();
        }

        public IEnumerator<ChatMessage> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ChatMessages.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    }


 public class ChatMessageGroupCollection : IEnumerable<ChatMessageGroup>
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<ChatMessageGroup> _groups;

        public ObservableCollection<ChatMessage> Source { get; set; }
        public CollectionViewSource Cvs { get; set; }

        public ChatMessageGroupCollection(ObservableCollection<ChatMessage> messages)
        {
            Source = messages;
            messages.CollectionChanged += Messages_CollectionChanged;

            var groups = messages
                .GroupBy(GetGroupKey)
                .Select(x => new ChatMessageGroup()
                {
                    Key = x.Key,
                    ChatMessages = x.OrderBy(GetGroupKey).ToObservableOrDefault()
                })
                .OrderBy(x => x.Key);

            _groups = new ObservableCollection<ChatMessageGroup>(groups);
            Cvs = new CollectionViewSource() { IsSourceGrouped = true, Source = _groups };
        }
...
```

Everything works fine in here except the changes inside group collection:

```
_groups.Add(new ChatMessageGroup()); -> this line reflect changes in ListView
```

but if I do like this: `_groups[0].ChatMessages.Add(new ChatMessage())` it doesn't work even though `ChatMessageGroup` is implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` and is raised every time `ChatMessages` `ObservableCollection` is changed. 
The workaround is to update ChatMessages and remove group from _groups and then add it again but it's not a solution. `Refresh()` on `CollectionViewSource` is not available in UWP. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Group headers can be implemented a few ways, so what are you trying to accomplish - can you update your question please?

Comment: I have a grouped CollectionViewSource. I want to update the content of the collection and ListView should update its content

Comment: @Zbigniew, were you able to solve this?  In WPF there's a CollectionViewSource.View.Refresh(), but in UWP there doesn't appear to be a solution!

Comment: @NeilTurner what other ways are there to implement group headers? I am having the same problem as Zbigniew and want to update (add/remove item) one of the groups.

Comment: @tipa I'll put together an answer for removing items and header items when using `CollectionViewSource` - spoiler: you have to handle it manually.

Comment: @NeilTurner awesome, looking forward to it. Handling it manually wouldn't be a showstopper for me, I just want it to get working anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst this doesn't technically qualify as an answer to the question I do think it might qualify as an architectural answer.

The way to make a grouped list view update based on the underlying collection changing in WPF is as simple as setting [`IsLiveGroupingRequested`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.islivegroupingrequested(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true` on the `CollectionViewSource` instance declared in XAML.

As I've been working my way through UWP (after nearly a decade of WPF) I've come to the conclusion that Microsoft are suggesting through omission that this isn't the right approach to the problem for UWP.  So going to the lengths of implementing the feature yourself could be construed as missing the point somewhat.

In my particular situation I've decided to change my approach entirely and implement the rendering as multiple instance of `ListView`s as opposed to forcing an old paradigm onto a new platform.

The result of this actually made me arrive at a solution that improved my UX to boot.

Food for thought ...